# How to emulate OpenLayers button click in C#

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, c#

I'm trying to call a click of a user using C # with the following code ( " C # :

> GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate ( javascript : void (
>   Document.getElementById ( ' idOfElement ' ) .click ( ) ) " ) ;

But this element is not triggered in Open API Layer .

How can I trigger an action using this code snippet ?

**What is the function calling this action ?**

Comment: Try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) to interact with UI elements on the page